# Let $f$ a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such $f(a)=f(b)$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such $f(a)=f(b)$
Prove that: the equation $$f(x) = f\left(x+\frac{b-a}{2}\right)$$ has at least a solution in $[a,b]$
I tried to use Tvi(intermediate value theorem) but i don't know how please i need a help

Comment: Have you heard this riddle.  A monk leaves the monastery at 7:00 AM, to hike up a trail to a cell at the top of the mountain.  He arrives at the cell at Noon.  Meditates for the afternoon, sleeps the night, and begins his hike down the trail at 7:00 arriving at the monastery at noon.  His walking speed is inconsistent on both the hike up and the hike down.  Is he ever in the same place in the trail at the same time of day on the hike up as the hike down?  Can you apply the logic of that riddle to this problem?

Comment: That "same place at the same time" question is easily answered if you have two monks, one at the top of the hill and one at the bottom at 7:00 AM, walking in opposite directions so that they have traded places by noon.  At some point they pass each other. $\qquad$

Comment: One monk  is $x$ who is traveling from $f(a)$ to $f(\frac{b-a}{2})$ and the other monk is $x + \frac {b-a}{2}$ traveling from $f(\frac{b-a}{2})$ going to $f(b) = f(a).$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the intermediate value theorem on
$$
g(x)=f(x)-f\left(x+\frac{b-a}2\right)
$$for $x=a$ and $x=\frac{b+a}2$.

Note that the equation doesn't make sense on all of $[a,b]$. It only makes sense for $x\in \left[a,\frac{b+a}2\right]$.

Comment: Then compare the values of $g(a)$ and $g\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)$ remembering that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

This the case $n=2$ of the Horizontal Chord Theorem: If $a< b$ and $f:[a,b]\to R$ is continuous with $f(a)=f(b),$  then for each $n\in N$ there exists $x_n\in [a, b-(b-a)/n]$ such that $f(x_n)=f(x_n+(b-a)/n).$

Proof:  Define $g:[a, b-\frac {b-a}{n}]\to R$ by $$g(x)=f (x+(b-a)/n))-f(x).$$ Then $g$ is continuous on its domain and $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}g(a+j(b-a)/n)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} [\;f(a+(j+1)(b-a)/n)-f(a+j(b-a)/n)\;]$$ which telescopes to $-f(a)+f(b),$  which is $0.$

Now since $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}g(a+j(b-a)/n)=0,$   the function $g$ cannot be always positive or always negative ; also  the domain of $g$ is a non-empty interval, and $g$ is continuous  .

So there must exist $x_n$ with $g(x_n)=0.$

Footnote. In the (trivial) case $n=1$ the domain of $g$ is the  interval $[a,a].$