# Let $f:[a,b]\mapsto[a,b]$ be continous, suppose $f(a)=f(b)$. Show that there exist $c \in [a,\frac{b+a}{2}]$ with $f(c)=f(c+\frac{b-a}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

I tried with defining another function

$h(x):= f(x)-y$ where $ f(\frac{a+b}{2})<y<f(a)=f(b)$

So that $h(\frac{a+b}{2})\cdot h(a)<0$ and $h(\frac{a+b}{2})\cdot h(b)<0$
and

therfore I have two points $x_{1}\in[a,\frac{a+b}{2}] , x_{2}\in [\frac{a+b}{2},b]$ with $h(x_{1})=0=h(x_{2})$.

But I can't tell anything about how much they are apart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can show the below claim is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702570/how-i-can-show-the-below-claim-is-true)  – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(c)%3Df(c%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb-a%7D%7B2%7D)%24&p=1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1830311/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2876444/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1053764/42969.

Comment: yes indeed, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather try
$g(c):=f(c)-f(c+\tfrac{b-a}2)$ for $a\le c\le\frac{a+b}2$ and show that $g(c)=0$ for some intermediate $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+\frac {b-a} 2)$. verify that $g(a)+g(\frac {a+b} 2)=0$. This implies that $g$ has opposite signs at $a$ and $\frac {a+b} 2$. Hence it vanishes at some point in the interval.